# how to override settings per test file in django?

Tags: python, django, pytest-django

I have two tests that when run at the same time fails:

```
pytest -s -v blog/tests/
```

but when run individually it passes:

```
pytest -s -v blog/tests/test_A.py
pytest -s -v blog/tests/test_B.py
```

I think the cause of this is both uses this pytest.fixture to override the settings:

**test_A.py**:

```
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def override_url(settings):
    settings.A_URL = f'https://{ip_host}:{port}'
```

**test_B.py**

```
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def override_url(settings):
    settings.B_URL = f'https://{ip_host}:{port}'
```

Is there a way to fix this fixture to avoid the tests failing when ran at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `autouse=True`

With the value set to ‘True’, all tests in this session just use the fixture automatically.